# Windows phone 7 Page Navigation

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

How to navigate between one project file to another in visual studio 2010 for windows phone so that we can use xaml files or use other cs files in each other.........

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need to do:

```
private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

You can find in detail from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx